# How to write REST API using firebase?

Tags: rest, firebase

I am very new to firebase. I used to write lots of REST API,

Is there a way in firebase to write REST API?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Access data in Realtime Database with the REST API?  Author your own REST API?

Comment: Both, in general whatever we can do with rest API like using the other framweorks

Comment: If you have two questions, maybe those should be split up into two different posts on SO.  They have completely different answers.  What other frameworks are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try read this**

[Firebase Database REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/)

**write REST API**

[Save Data Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data)